# To find intersection between a Object and array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm beginner to javascript.

How to find intersection between a array and object in javascript.

Lets take:

```
   var use = [{name:'jony'}, {name: 'raja'}, {name: 'papy'}];
```

And array as:

```
   var now = ['jony', 'raja', 'singh'];
```

Now how can I get result as

```
   var result = ['jony', 'raja'];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, like looping the two arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = use.filter(function(e) {
    return now.indexOf(e.name) > -1;
}).map(function(e) { return e.name; });

console.log(result);  // ["jony", "raja"]
```